# Is there any more advanced tutorial for using python on Google AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm looking for a tutorial that begins where the [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/) ends. In other words a more comprehensive tutorial on Python + Google AppEngine + webapp2

Any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the [webapp improved documentation](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/). Also, there is the book 'Programming Google App Engine', which its 2nd edition is supposed to be ready in October (see its [webpage](http://ae-book.appspot.com/) for details).

Answer (score 1):

As for webapp2, try looking at http://blog.notdot.net/2011/11/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-2-Webapp-and-templates (and basically anything by Nick Johnson). **EDIT:** Sebastian Kreft's suggestion is more what you want, I'm guessing. But still read Nick's stuff :)

As for a more advanced tutorial, a cop-out answer (that I'll recommend) is just reading the docs and trying stuff out yourself. For instance, reading through [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview) (same docs, just further down the left-nav) will give you an overview of the variety of services/api/etc. that are available in the SDK. I'm as far from an expert as you'll find, but doing that (in combination with creating my own problems and solving with the help of the people on this site) will definitely help you learn.

Answer (score 0):

This is not using webapp2, but at [this python codelab](https://sites.google.com/site/gdevelopercodelabs/app-engine/python-codelab) is similar to the guestbook tutorial, but with 2 extras sections showing how to use other App Engine API like:

- Memcache
- Mail API
- Channel API

And a standalone exercise at the end showing:

- UrlFetch,
- Cron
- Task Queues

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial series is also quite nice because it shows how to properly structure your code using webapp2. Downside is that db(old standard) is used instead of ndb(new standard).

http://tutorialzine.com/2011/01/getting-started-with-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 0):

Google have done a ton of work since the webapp days.

In late 2016, starting from scratch with a new project on Google Cloud/App Engine, you can now step through a tutorial which clones a **quickstart project** for you and then runs it from the gloud console.

This can be referenced at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart. It is essentially a Python Flask 0.10 project and all the Flask components are placed in a /lib directory.

There is also a tutorial for the Beta release of the Flexible Environment at https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/hello-world. In the notes they reference a number of frameworks in addition to Flask, specifically Django, Pyramid, Bottle, Tornado and of course web.py