# Google App Engine Beginner

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I am new to HTML and have been given an assignment to replicate the website found at http://guessinggame-1178.appspot.com/ using python and webapp2. I have no idea what I'm doing and the assignment is due very soon, so any amount of help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't ask a specific programming question, it asks for vague help with a school assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Check the HelloWorld python example  using Google App Engine. This should be a good start. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python and [Is there any more advanced tutorial for using python on Google AppEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977563/is-there-any-more-advanced-tutorial-for-using-python-on-google-appengine) should help.